# p:autocomplete always return null in bean on ItemSelect

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm having some issues with p:autocomplete, Primefaces , the auto complete is ok, but when the user select some value, I force an ajax request to handle the selected item, but the item always return null.

How can i solve this?

Here's the view:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Cliente: " />
            <p:autoComplete value="#{autoCompleteCliente.clienteSelecionado}"
                converter="ClienteConverter" style="margin-left: 8px;width: 200px;"
                id="clientecomplete"
                completeMethod="#{autoCompleteCliente.completeCliente}"
                var="cliente" itemLabel="#{cliente.nome}" itemValue="#{cliente}"
                forceSelection="true">
                <f:facet name="itemtip">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/chamadosIcon.png"
                                width="40" height="50" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="Codigo: " />
                        <h:outputText id="codigo" value="#{cliente.codigo}" />
                        <h:outputText value="CNPJ " />
                        <h:outputText id="CNPJ" value="#{cliente.cnpj}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>


                <p:ajax listener="#{autoCompleteCliente.handleSelect}" event="itemSelect"
                    process=":chamadoEdicao:clientecomplete" />



            </p:autoComplete>
```

and Here's the bean:

```
  @ManagedBean(name = "autoCompleteCliente")
  @ViewScoped
  public class ClienteAutoComplete {

private Cliente clienteSelecionado;
private List<Cliente> clientes;

public ClienteAutoComplete() {
    clientes = ClienteConverter.todosClientes;
}


@PostConstruct
public void construct() {
    System.out.println("Iniciou autoCompleteCliente");
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("Fechou autoCompleteCliente");
}

public Cliente getclienteSelecionado() {
    return clienteSelecionado;
}

public void setclienteSelecionado(Cliente clienteSelecionado) {
    this.clienteSelecionado = clienteSelecionado;
}

/**
 * Método para autocompletar o nome do cliente para disponibilizar na view
 * de cadastro de chamado.
 * 
 * @author helios-kob
 * @param query
 *            String
 * @return complete List<String>
 * 
 */
public List<Cliente> completeCliente(String query) {
    ArrayList<Cliente> resultados = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    for (Cliente cliente : clientes) {
        if (cliente.getNome().contains(query)) {
            resultados.add(cliente);
        }
    }

    return resultados;

}

public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    String value = (String) event.getObject();
    System.out.println("selected "+value);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, the main problem was on ClienteConverter, It was returning null by a if that compared one of attributes of cliente, didnn't match any.

If Help anyone, The converter comes first.

Comment: could you explain your answer? I am having the same issue